# .joins? .include? Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I'm trying to view a table in rails console and can't figure it out.

A cart `has_many :line_items` and a Line item `belongs_to :cart`.
I'm trying to get a table that shows a `cart_id` with its containing `line_items` in the console. Is this possible?

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
cart = Cart.find(1)
cart.line_items
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I am answering your question correctly, but to retrieve a record and to lazy load it's `line_items` associations we can do the following.

```
cart = Card.includes(:line_items).find(card_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:    `LineItem.where(cart_id: id)`